# Layout of old Word Documents destroyed in Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, page-layout-view

My customer and I use Office 365. All the old contract documents (*.doc) of his were made with various previous Word versions and carefully taylored to fit on one page. When he now opens the old documents 4-5 paragraphs are wrapped to page 2. Thus the original document cannot be reproduced.

It looks like the line spacing is too big.

Strange though: on two of my computers everything looks good.

I think I ruled out the following points but none did help:

- the font is installed on both machines (Lucida Sans Unicode / 8.5 pt.)
- All Settings in Word-Options -> Extended -> Layout options and Compatibility options are identical (and were not changed beforehand)
- I installed the same printer driver on both machines (MIcrosoft PS Class Driver) because I know that printer drivers used to influence the layout
- I transferred *my* normal.dotm to *his* PC.

See below screenshots to give you an idea. Any help is greatly appreciated!

this is correct:
[image: formatted correctly]

this is not (2 pages)
[image: formatted incorrectly 1/2]
[image: formatted incorrectly 2/2]

Comment: If you hold the first page of each on top of each other and look "through" them to a bright light, do the words on each line match and it is the vertical spacing that is wrong, or are the words off left-to-right as well?

Comment: Also, this looks like a order form/purchase order type thing.  Is it standard enough you could make it a fillable PDF ?

Comment: Try opening the document in free LibreOffice Writer. It is surprisingly better able to open different versions of MS Word docs than can any one particular version of Word.

Comment: @ivanivan it seems to affect the line spacing _only_. The words on each line match. I will prepare a new document template with proper & modern formatting for the client, but the problem with the old contracts persists. So PDF is not an option here.

Comment: There may be some compatibility issues between different versions of Office. For more information, refer to [Compatibility changes between versions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compatibility-changes-between-versions-692289af-b760-4698-8326-14b2edcd6552). Were the documents opened under Compatibility Mode? Generally, compatibility mode preserves the layout of the document. If you convert the document to modern mode, there may be some layout differences. If you don't work with older versions of Word, I suggest you use the new version of the format (such as .docx).

Comment: If it is simply the line spacing, I think you can control that under the page or paragraph formatting, may be worth trying to reduce it a little bit and see if you can get things back onto one page.

Comment: Thank you @all, the case is dismissed. No solution found, I am doing some manual work now and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is dismissed. No solution found, I am doing some manual work now and move on. It must have something to do with line spacing handling and the font (Lucida Sans Unicode 8.5) and Word formatting is crap anyway :/

I blame the customer for not working correctly over the last 10 years ;)

Comment: I don't upvote your andwer just because of `I blame the customer`. Customer just used the stupid thing. I was first anoyed that LibreOffice doesn't properly format the docs. Then I figured MS also doesn't know how to format them... Badly defined file format and I'm not sure recent docx would be better after some time. /but I upvoted question /

Comment: Well @akostadinov you don't have to ... It's not an answer, after all. Of course I don't really blame the customer, but if he had switched to docx 10 years earlier the problem might not have occurred.